# How do I remove an IKEA shelf which is stuck on top of another?

Tags: removal, shelving

I have bought and installed several IKEA shelves (Besta line), and I installed the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xquam.jpg) (w x d x h: 60 cm x 40 cm x 123 cm):

[image: shelf top]

on top of [another](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/S39047657/#/S29132793) (60 cm x 40 cm x 38 cm; [instructions](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/assembly_instructions/besta-frame__AA-1272056-4_pub.pdf)):

[image: shelf 1]

In order to attach the top one on the bottom one (besides of mounting them to the wall) they give you two systems:

1. clamps:

   [image: clamp]
2. stickers (double sided foam tape):

   [image: stickers]

Now I want to remove them from each other; removing the clamp is easy, but removing 'stickers' is not. There are four stickers between the shelves.

**How can I (easily) remove the shelves from each other without damaging them?**

Comment: Are the "stickers" double-sided foam tape? If so, slide a thin metal or plastic blade between the cabinets and slice it. Use something with no serrations to prevent surface damage. A putty knife or painter's bar might do.

Comment: @isherwood: Yes it is double-sided foam tape. Thanks for the idea, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 2):

Use the thinnest putty knife you can obtain to release the double stick tape.

To get the remaining adhesive off, I would first use a dry rag and try to rub it off. Always rub in the same direction. If that doesn't do it, I would then use "Goof Off", alcohol or acetone to remove the adhesive left behind - first testing a hidden area with the product to make sure you won't effect the shelf laminate. You never know, most laminates are very durable, but...

Heating the adhesive can also work, but you need to have some care as the shelf laminate is also glued on to the wood product.

Hopefully, with care, you can get it all off just with the putty knife, but you may damage the laminate if you go at it too hard, so think of it as a 2 or 3 step process.  good luck!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. You shouldn't post comments as answers (wait until you have enough rep), but this seems like a decent answer to me.

Comment: thanks, it started out like a comment, but I just kept at it and turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Heat gun or hair dryer.  It'll lift the adhesive.  If you do it one corner at a time, slide a piece of wax paper under the ones you've unstuck.

Comment: Thanks @Joe! I'll try it together with isherwood's idea.

Comment: @agold chances are the air won't get into the cracks well enough to soften the glue/tape, so a knife is going to get the shelves apart. But as for removing the sticky stuff after that, a hair dryer is the way to go.